# How to filter List With LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

I need to filter a `List<Students>` into `StudentsWitHighestDebts`.

The criteria is that only students where `ZachetDidNotPass` has maximum value and `maximum-1` in all `List<Students>` are included in the result.

```
var StudentsWitHighestDebts = students
               .Where(s => s.ZachetDidNotPass.(some condition))
               .OrderBy(s => s.Name)
               .ToList();
```

For example, given a list of students that have `ZachetDidNotPass` values `0 1 2 5 6 7`. The resulting `StudentsWitHighestDebts` should only contain the students with `7 and 6` values in `ZachetDidNotPass`.

Comment: Just put in another `Where`.

Comment: It's really such a stupid question, that I need to be minused hard :(?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Still can't understand - what condition will be in (some condition) to check only for max? And then, yes i will add one more Where with max-1...

Comment: Not sure, since I don't really get your question. Can you use the `Max` extension method? For `Max -1`, use `OrderByDescending` and take the second item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First option: take 2 highest debts and filter students by ZachetDidNotPass:

```
var highestDebts = students.Select(s => s.ZachetDidNotPass)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p).Take(2).ToArray();
var studentsWitHighestDebts = students
    .Where(s => highestDebts.Contains(s.ZachetDidNotPass))
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.ZachetDidNotPass).ToList();
```

Second option - group by ZachetDidNotPass, sort groups by key descending, take top 2 groups and select students from groups

```
var studentsWitHighestDebts = students.GroupBy(s => s.ZachetDidNotPass)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).Take(2)
    .SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
```

And third option (take students with highest debt and highestDebt - 1)

```
var highestDebt = students.Max(s => s.ZachetDidNotPass);

var studentsWitHighestDebts = students
    .Where(s => s.ZachetDidNotPass == highestDebt || s.ZachetDidNotPass == highestDebt - 1)
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.ZachetDidNotPass).ToList();
```

Comment: The second option is not optimal in time. You should explain the difference between the first and third option. For example if the value are `0 1 2 3 4 5 7` should we take the students with a `5`?